# Primitive of $\frac{3x^4-1}{(x^4+x+1)^2}$

Tags: integration

How to find primitive of:
$$\frac{3x^4-1}{(x^4+x+1)^2}$$
I am having a faint idea of a type which may or maynot be in the primitve, i.e.:
$$\frac{p(x)}{x^4+x+1}$$
The problem is I am not getting an idea of a substitution to solve this problem.

I might show my work but it is totally useless, atleast in this case.

---

For reference:
[image]

Comment: Apply [partial fraction decomposition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_fraction_decomposition), then integrate each term.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut to this too exists an easy solution by substitution[that I don't know], which becomes lengthier to calculate via partial fraction,

Comment: You won't escape using logarithm and arctangent in the answer, though.

Comment: Take a look output of [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral+%5Cfrac%7B3x%5E4-1%7D%7B%28x%5E4%2Bx%5E2%2B1%29%5E2%7D).

Comment: @Tunk-Fey As often, WA does it the wrong way, using complex numbers where they are really useless: Maxima gives an answer involving only real logarithms and arctangents. However, it can't be simpler than that. Rather easy with partial fractions, though cumbersome.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut I have nothing but W|A :)

Comment: computers are not as intelligent as human, they can't do everything like humans. they can't innovate new substitutions except the one taught to them, that's why this question is suited to us

Comment: @Tunk-Fey [Maxima](http://sourceforge.net/projects/maxima/files/) is free :p

Comment: btw http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=diffrentiate+-x%2F%28x%5E4%2Bx%2B1%29

Comment: @Aditya You can innovate as much as you want, there will be logarithms and arctangent in the answer, period.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut Ahh, how stupid am I!? Thanks for the link :)

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut Is there a guideline for such serious typos?

Comment: With the change in the question, everything is easy, but any little change, like changing the $1$ on top to $2$, turns it into a nightmare.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\bf{My\; Solution::}$ Let $$\displaystyle I = \int\frac{3x^4-1}{(x^4+x+1)^2}dx = \int\frac{3x^4-1}{x^2\cdot \left(x^3+1+x^{-1}\right)^2}dx = \int\frac{(3x^2-x^{-2})}{(x^3+1+x^{-1})^2}dx$$

Now Let $$(x^3+1+x^{-1}) = t\;,$$ Then $$(3x^2-x^{-2})dx = dt$$

So $$\displaystyle I = \int\frac{1}{t^2}dt = -\frac{1}{t}+\mathbb{C} = -\frac{1}{x^3+1+x^{-1}}+\mathbb{C} = -\left(\frac{x}{x^4+x+1}\right)+\mathbb{C}$$

Comment: what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

$$ \int \frac{3x^4-1}{(x^4+x+1)^2} = \int \frac{3x^4+4x^3-4x^3-1}{(x^4+x+1)^2}$$
$$ \int \frac{3x^4+4x^3-4x^3-1}{(x^4+x+1)^2} = \int \frac{3x^4+4x^3}{(x^4+x+1)^2}- \int \frac{4x^3+1}{(x^4+x+1)^2}$$
Consider, 
$$ \int \frac{3x^4+4x^3}{(x^4+x+1)^2} = \int \frac{4x^3(x+1)-x^4}{(x^4+x+1)^2} = \int \frac{(4x^3+1)(x+1)+(-1)(x^4+x+1)}{(x^4+x+1)^2}= -\frac{x+1}{x^4+x+1}$$
Hint: Can you see quotient rule here?

And , obviously 
$$ \int \frac{4x^3+1}{(x^4+x+1)^2} = -\frac{1}{x^4+x+1} $$
Hint: Use substitution $t=x^4+x+1$

So concluding, 
$$  \int \frac{3x^4-1}{(x^4+x+1)^2} = -\frac{x}{x^4+x+1} \Box$$

Comment: that's just working backwards